# Docker kubernetes - unauthorized: authentication required

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have setup a new Kubernetes v1.5 cluster.

I locally created a new docker image using :

```
# MAIN IMAGE
FROM gcr.io/google_containers/nginx-slim
```

I created it using the command :

```
docker build -t myapp:1 .
```

I can see that the image is avaiable and running :

```
docker ps | grep app
d6fc0508e56b        myapp:1                                                                                                                            "nginx -g 'daemon ..."   31 seconds ago      Up 30 seconds       0.0.0.0:32354->80/tcp
```

Now I am trying to use the same image in a kubernetes deployment.

```
kubectl run app-deployment --image myapp:1 --replicas=1 --port=80
```

But doing so does not start the pod and I get the ERROR :

```
  19s   3s  2   {kubelet 10.0.0.17} spec.containers{app-deployment} Normal  Pulling     pulling image "myapp:1"
  18s   2s  2   {kubelet 10.0.0.17} spec.containers{app-deployment} Warning Failed      Failed to pull image "myapp:1": unauthorized: authentication required
  18s   2s  2   {kubelet 10.0.0.17}                 Warning FailedSync  Error syncing pod, skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "app-deployment" with ErrImagePull: "unauthorized: authentication required"
```

The files `/root/.docker/config.json` & `/var/lib/kubelet/.dockercfg` are currently empty. Is there something Ive missed in setting up Kubernetes ?

Comment: Where is kubernetes deployed?

Comment: I have created 2 VMs [1 master 1 minion] (CentOS 7) on my virtual.

Comment: Ok and where are you building your images? In the nodes (both) or in your dev machine?

Comment: On my master node only. I built the same image on the minion and now it works. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are building a custom docker image, you have to build it in every node of your cluster that the scheduler could put the pod into.

Furthermore, you need yo specify in your `PodSpec` an `imagePullPolicy` of `ifNotPresent` to indicate the `kubelet` not to try to download your image if it is already present.

This should make your image work, but I strongly suggest you to push your image in a `docker registry` and let the nodes pull it from there.